# awk: runaway regular expression

Tags: bash

I can run command on ubuntu:

```
free | grep Mem | awk '{print $3/$2 * 100.0}'
```

And get result:

```
20.1092
```

But when I try to put it in alias:

```
alias memTotal="free | grep Mem | awk '{print $3/$2 * 100.0}'"
```

It don't work:

```
$ memTotal
awk: line 1: runaway regular expression / * 100.0} ...
```

Comment: Use a function. No worrying about quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
alias memTotal='free | grep Mem | awk '\''{print $3/$2 * 100.0}'\'
```

Breaking down the quoting, that's

```
'free | grep Mem | awk '
```

followed by an escaped single quote `\'`, then the quoted awk expression `'{print $3/$2 * 100.0}'` and finally the escaped literal closing quote `\'`